# Disabling/Stopping Data from Refreshing in DHTMLxGantt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I have a DHTMLxGantt chart I'm using that needs to have links on specific tasks without interfering with either the text on the data bars or in the description when you click on a data bar.

I have gotten the links to apply in a way that works for what I'm working on, however once you start scrolling and a task "leaves" the screen, it loses the href attached to it on load and defaults back to just showing the task name from the data passed into the API.

Is there a setting or some kind of function that I might have missed that would disable this data refresh on scrolling? I'm guessing this is a built-in feature with DHTMLxGantt, and so if this is not possible then we will have to proceed with just passing in the link HTML into the data array we give the API.

Thanks for any advice in the future.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the DOM objects inside the Gantt container, all the changes will be lost after Gantt repaints the data. If you need to display custom data or HTML elements inside the task bars, you need to specify them in the `task_text` template:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_task_text_template.html

Here are examples:

https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/gloya4d1

https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/7kfi9tc4